# Caching of Classes / Object lists in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have two classes, a User and a UserGroup class.

A User has one UserGroup and a UserGroup can have many Users

When I create a new UserGroup, say "Group 1", it appears in my list of UserGroups and I can edit it and save it without problems.

However, when I go to create a new User, I can see and select my new UserGroup, "Group 1" from the dropdown list, but when I go to save I get a validation error because Rails doesn't see the UserGroup id as belonging to the current list of UserGroup ids.

Here are pieces of what I believe are the relevant code:

user_group model:

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  ...
  # class methods
  def self.full_list_of_ids
    UserGroup.all.pluck(:id)
  end
end
```

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  ...
  validates :user_group_id, inclusion: { in: UserGroup.full_list_of_ids }, unless: 'Rails.env.test?'
  ...
  ...
end
```

The error that occurs when I try to save the new User with the new UserGroup is a validation error so it seems the code within full_list_of_ids returns back an older version of the UserGroup ids even although within the views, I can see the new UserGroup.

I am running this within my development environment at the moment.

So is there a way to force Rails to reload the version of UserGroups in memory or something else?

It seems like it's just caching things too much to me. Surely a newly created object within a class should cause a reload automatically?

I should point out that I can change the UserGroup of any User to an older UserGroup no problems.

If you need any more information, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You should add the form code, the controller method to validate the user param and the post data received by the server when creating an User(dev server terminal).

Comment: @lain Rails caching sql query only for one request. If group was added in previous request ids list for group must be new if you did not cache it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 11 years I haven't seen someone using an inclusion validation like this. What you want to do is [according to the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_group
  validate :user_group, presence: true
end
```

Now to explain why you ran into this problem: the argument of `validate` are evaluated when the class is loaded, so the `UserGroup.full_list_of_ids` is evaluated into an array and that array is not updated after creating a new usergroup. Don't ask for a work-around, use the `presence` validator instead.

Comment: Old validates_incusiion_of https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of works with lamda, maybe `validate :attribure, inclusion` works too.

Comment: yes you're right kunashir but I still would prefer the `presence` validator because that one is meant for such a case.

Comment: Actually Thomas, I did have the following lines:

  # relationships
  belongs_to :user_group

  # validations
  ....validates :user_group_id, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }

but when I remove the "validates :user_group_id, inclusion" lines, my specs which check for creating a user with an invalid user group id to give an error, still work so I guess the "belongs_to :user_group" automatically checks that the assigned user group actually exists?

Comment: Yes, belongs_to get validated automatically unless you make it optional: `belongs_to :user_group, optional: true`

Comment: Great, thanks. Also thanks for the original explanation.